# Avoid bfseries from bolding \pm in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm using siunitx to successfully align my column content along the `\pm`:

```
\begin{table}[b]
    \centering  
    \robustify\bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{
            c       S[detect-weight, table-format=1.1(1)]}
        \toprule
        Header1 & {Header2} \\
                    & {Sub} \\
        \midrule
        A2          & -6,2 \pm 1,3 \\
        A3          & 4,8 \pm 1,7 \\
        A7          & \bfseries 5,7 +- 2,0 \\
        A12         & 5,9 \pm 2,1 \\        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption.}
    \label{table:mwe}
\end{table}
```

[image: table]

Furthermore, I'd like to point out one special data set by using `\bfseries`, which happens to also boldify the +- sign, which isn't intended. I would like to avoid this, since there is no additional information within the bold +- and the size of the +- symbol increases as well.
Any ideas, that don't point in the direction of column separators?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use the `b` font series so the numbers will have the same size.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,etoolbox,booktabs}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering
\renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\pm}{\mathbin{\mbox{\unboldmath$\mathchar"2206$}}}

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[detect-weight, table-format=-1.1(1),mode=text]
}
\toprule
Header1 & {Header2} \\
        & {Sub} \\
\midrule
A2          & -6,2 \pm 1,3 \\
A3          & 4,8 \pm 1,7 \\
A7          & \bfseries 5,7 +- 2,0 \\
A12         & 5,9 \pm 2,1 \\        
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption.}
\label{table:mwe}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

The above no longer works with `siunitx` version 3. Something more complex is needed not for unbolding the `\pm` symbol, but for obtaining nonextended bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

% this is only necessary for Computer Modern
\DeclareMathVersion{tablebold}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{tablebold}{OT1}{cmr} {b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {tablebold}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}  {tablebold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { siunitx / series-version-mapping } { b = tablebold }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering

% a couple of local redefinitions
\RenewDocumentCommand{\pm}{}{\mathbin{\mbox{\mathversion{normal}$\mathchar"2206$}}}
\newcommand{\B}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % for brevity

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[detect-weight,table-format=-1.1(1)]
}
\toprule
Header1 & {Header2} \\
        & {Sub} \\
\midrule
A2          &   -6,2 \pm 1,3 \\
A3          &    4,8 \pm 1,7 \\
A7          & \B 5,7 +-  2,0 \\
A12         &    5,9 +-  2,1 \\        
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption.}
\label{table:mwe}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Comment: Thanks again for the proposed solution, that was working back when the question was asked.
After updating the Tex packages, the mwe here returns an error, saying "Missing $ inserted. A" on line 23, which is the one in the table starting with "A3". If the \renewcommand{\pm} is commented it compiles, but the bold pm returns (obviously).

Comment: @jo3ran `siunitx` version 3 has changed quite a lot. Check the update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch back to normal font for the pm, the alignment is already broken by the bold numbers, so no additional harm done

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[b]
    \centering  
%    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{
            c       S[detect-weight, table-format=1.1(1)]}
        \toprule
        Header1 & {Header2} \\
                    & {Sub} \\
        \midrule
        A2          & -6,2 \pm 1,3 \\
        A3          & 4,8 \pm 1,7 \\
        A7          & \bfseries 5,7 {\normalfont$\pm$} 2,0 \\
        A12         & 5,9 \pm 2,1 \\        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption.}
    \label{table:mwe}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to point out that this method gives you inconsistent decimal separators. Even upon usage of the `output-decimal-marker` option one gets:  `.` for non bold entries and `,` for bold entries.